# Is this cast to IDisposable correct?

Tags: c#, lambda, task-parallel-library

In MSFT's [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957), on page 11, Stephen Toub has the following code illustrating the wrapping of a Task around a Timer callback.

```
public static Task<DateTimeOffset> Delay(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<DateTimeOffset>();
    new Timer(self =>
    {
        ((IDisposable)self).Dispose();  //<--this is the line in question
        tcs.TrySetResult(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
    }).Change(millisecondsTimeout, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

On line 6, he casts `self` as `IDisposable`. If I'm reading this lambda expression correctly, self "goes to" a [TimerCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx), which doesn't implement `IDisposable`. Am I reading it wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter `self` is argument passed when your delegate (lambda) is invoked by `Timer`. According to MSDN this delegate is of type `TimerCallback`:

```
public delegate void TimerCallback(Object state)
```

When you are not giving state in Timer constructor, it uses Timer instance itself as state:

> Call this constructor when you want to use the Timer object itself as the state object.

So self will be instance of Timer which can be safely casted as IDisposable.
Although type of parameter is `object` that means it has to be subclass of `object` which can be any type in .NET.

Comment: Good, thanks. I got that self is the Object parameter to this delegate. But I don't see why it is the Timer. In other words, it looks like self should be just some Object, not the Timer.

Comment: Thanks. Let me ask this way: 'self' is not a reserved word. It doesn't automatically refer to the new Timer. So what in this syntax causes it to refer to the Timer?

Comment: It is not in the syntax, it is the bahavior of Timer.

Answer (score 0):

No, self is the Timer object. The code:

```
self =>
    {
        ((IDisposable)self).Dispose();  //<--this is the line in question
        tcs.TrySetResult(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
    }
```

follow this format:

```
(explicitly-typed-parameter-list)=> { statements }
```

Which creates a delegate while the type of the input parameter is Timer